# Is there a way to use ip:port:auth:password proxies for Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, proxy, webdriver

I am currently using privately made proxies, which have an ip:port:auth:password format for their proxies.

Is there a way to implement this into Selenium WebDriver for Python?

Comment: I think this is specific to the navigator you are using. For example, using Firefox and a pac file for proxy configuration I had something like profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 2)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", urlproxy) whereas with chrome I had chrome_profile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_profile.add_argument(f'--proxy-auto-dedect=true')
    chrome_profile.add_argument(f'--proxy-pac-url={urlproxy}')

Comment: use https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/